# Magento maintenance mode disable

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, maintenance-mode

I have a magento eshop and I get maintenance mode only on product page.

1. There is no maintenance.flag file in root
2. I have cleared my cache and session
3. I dont have a maintenance extension installed
4. I have deactivated all of the extensions so as to check if any of
   them causes the problem

however, I still have this issue.

Could someone possibly know why this is happening?

Comment: Please check in index.php is there any IP restriction for it.

Comment: No, there is no restriction.